# Using multiple content views (XML and canvas) on Android

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue with using the Canvas to draw my Math equation and text, and haivng text boxes at the bottom of the screen to input data for a result.  On my current setup i can have either the buttons and text boxes, or the equation and variable names.  Here is my code from the java class

```
    package com.soraingraven.suprRef;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class PerfectGasLaw extends Activity {
    class RenderView extends View {
        //For the Text
        Paint paint;
        Typeface font;

        //For the pics
        Bitmap PGL;

        public RenderView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint = new Paint();

            //Attempt to load the bitmaps
            try {               
                AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
                InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("PerfGasLaw.png");
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
                PGL = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("BitmapText", "bobargb8888.png format: " + PGL.getConfig());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //we should really close our input streams here.
            }
        }

        //Drawing text and pics
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paint.setTypeface(font);
            paint.setTextSize(32);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            canvas.drawText("P = Pressure in Atmospheres", 25, 350, paint);
            canvas.drawText("V = Volume in Liters", 25, 400, paint);
            canvas.drawText("n = Number of moles", 25, 450, paint);
            canvas.drawText("R = Gas Constant", 25, 500, paint);
            canvas.drawText(" - (0.0821 Liter-Atmospheres / K / mole)", 50, 550, paint);
            canvas.drawText("T = Temperature in K", 25, 600, paint);
            canvas.drawText("If Constant Pressure - V1/V2 = T1/T2", 25, 650, paint);
            canvas.drawText("If Constant Temperature - P1/P2 = V2/V1", 25, 700, paint);
            canvas.drawText("If Constant Volume - P1/P2 = T1/T2", 25, 750, paint);

            canvas.drawBitmap(PGL, 25, 25, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setContentView(new RenderView(this));
    }
}
```

And the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please assist me in doing this.  Also if anyone could tell me how to grab the input from a text field like this it would be helpful.  Also I am attempting to do this using the least amount of XML possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass your own, say `EquationView` from a `View` so that view has your onDraw method().

Then in the XML you would place your view, like

```
<mypackage.equation.EquationView ... 
  android:layout_width=...
  android:layout_height=...
/>
```

along with those `EditText` and `Button`

Comment: would EquationView be different from RenderView in my code?  This is a separate activity chosen from a list if that makes a difference.

Comment: That would be 'RenderView extends View' and it will be in the xml file of your Activity. Within the Activity you would find your render View by findViewById so you can access your view if you need to.

Comment: Im getting this error when putting the package into my xml file.


Description Resource Path Location Type
Attribute name "com.soraingraven.suprRef.RenderView" associated with an element type "package" must be followed by the ' = ' character. main.xml /Super Reference/res/layout line 109 Android XML Format Problem


I have placed it like this

<package com.soraingraven.suprRef.RenderView
            android:id="@+id/drawable"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

It is inside a relative layout if that makes a difference